# IAM Roles for managing Google Cloud Platform APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iam

We have recently set up an account with Google Cloud Platform purely so we can utilise some of the APIs in our projects, we are not using any other aspect (except Billing and IAM).

We have one user who is the owner of the project, but want to assign our DevOps guy permission to manage the APIs and keys for use in the live deployments.

I have tried all sorts of roles, and even attempted to set up a custom role with just the permissions required, however I cannot for the life of me work out what permission is needed. Through trial and error I've managed to allow him to enable an API but creating the API key is still out of reach. Obviously I could set him as the project editor but that enables everything else too and so is too broad.

Can anyone give me a link to a proper list of roles and permissions (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles does not mention API keys as far as I can tell) or even tell me the exact permissions that are the bare minimum required to enable an API and create/edit keys for said APIs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the **Service Management** role called **API Key User**?

**Role**: roles/servicemanagement.apiKeyUser
**Title**: API Key User
**Description**: Access to get and list API Keys. Allows consumption of project read and write quota.
**Resource Type(s)**: Organization, Project

I believe this should do what you want.